# Prove that the every Cauchy sequence in $CS_{\Bbb R(x)}/R=\lbrace [(u_n)]|(u_n)\in CS_{\Bbb R(x)}\rbrace$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

Consider the field of rational functions $\Bbb R(x)$. Let $(u_n), (v_n)$ be sequences with terms in the field of rational functions.

Define the equivalence relation $R$ by $((u_n),(v_n))\in R\Leftrightarrow lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(u_n-v_n)=0$.

Consider the field of rational functions.

It is $\Bbb R (x)=\lbrace \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|f,g\in \Bbb R[x],g\ne0\rbrace$

Define $P=\lbrace p(x)|p(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\in \Bbb R[x]\land$ the leading coefficients of $f(x),g(x)$ are of the same sign $\rbrace$.

Define for $p(x),q(x)\in \Bbb R(x), p(x)\ge q(x) \Leftrightarrow p(x)-q(x)\in P\cup \lbrace 0\rbrace$.

For every $u=\frac{f}{g}\in \Bbb R(x)$,Define $|u|=max\lbrace u,-u\rbrace$

Define Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R(x)$ as: A sequence $(u_n)$ is Cauchy if $(\forall \epsilon \in P)(\exists N\in \Bbb N)(n,m>N\Rightarrow |u_n-u_m|<\epsilon)$

**As the way of getting $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$, extend the field of rational functions by means of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences.**

For the field of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequence in field of rational functions. Prove that every Cauchy sequence converges in the new field we get.

It seems that it is not quite same as the proof of every Cauchy sequence converges in $\Bbb R$. Could someone please give a proof? Thanks so much!

EDIT: It is seen in "conterexamples in analysis" without a proof.
[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but shouldn't you have some norm on the polynomial ring? (How do you define $\lim_{n\to\infty}(u_n-v_n)$.), Also, on the completion, you'd need a norm to define what a Cauchy sequence is (I guess that one just lifts from the other one, no?)

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand which is lifting from means. I will edit.

Comment: I meant that you define the norm of a Cauchy sequence (or its class) to be the limit of the norms of the terms of the sequence. Maybe lifting was not the best word here.

I still don't get it. You have a rational function $u$ and talk about $\max\{u,-u\}$: what is the order on the rational functions?

Comment: @martin.koeberl I have edited to explain the order.

Comment: Can you say what difficulty you have generalizing the proof for real numbers?

Comment: @EricWofsey The book says that $\Bbb R(x)$ is not dense in $CS_{\Bbb R(x)}/R$. But for proving that $\Bbb R$ is complete we require $\Bbb Q$ dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Where does the book say that?  I don't believe that's true, and I can't find any statement like that anywhere in the book...

Comment: @EricWofsey The "rational numbers" of the ordered field $K$ of Example 4 are not dense in $K$ on page 16. But I think maybe I have misunderstood the statement...... So may I please ask do you mean that we can prove that every cauchy sequence converges here as exactly the same way of proving $\Bbb R$ is complete?

Comment: All "the 'rational numbers' are not dense in $\mathbb{R}(x)$" means is that the unique subfield of $\mathbb{R}(x)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}(x)$.  This has nothing to do with whether $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is dense in its Cauchy completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually all of the usual proof of this fact for real numbers uses nothing special about the field $\mathbb{Q}$ (besides just that it is an ordered field).  So almost all of the steps apply immediately when you replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with the ordered field $\mathbb{R}(x)$.  The one special thing about $\mathbb{Q}$ that is used is the fact that for every rational number $q>0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $q>1/N$.  This is used, for instance, in saying that you can test whether a sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy by just testing whether the differences $|x_n-x_m|$ eventually become smaller than $1/N$ for each $N$.  To prove every Cauchy sequence $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, you then pick Cauchy sequences of rational numbers representing each $y_n$ and use a diagonal argument to find a limit of $(y_n)$, using the fact that you only need to make the relevant differences eventually smaller than $1/N$ for each $N$.

So to make this argument with $\mathbb{Q}$ replaced by a more general ordered field $K$, all you need to know about $K$ is that there exists a sequence $(\epsilon_N)$ of positive elements of $K$ such that for any $q>0$ in $K$, there exists $N$ such that $q>\epsilon_N$.  You can then use $\epsilon_N$ as a replacement for $1/N$ in the diagonal argument.

In the case of $K=\mathbb{R}(x)$, such a sequence is $\epsilon_N=1/x^N$.  Indeed, if $f(x)/g(x)\in K$ is a positive element, it is straightforward to verify that $f(x)/g(x)>1/x^N$ as long as $N>\deg g-\deg f$.

(In fact, if $K$ is an ordered field such that no such sequence $(\epsilon_N)$ exists, then the result is still true, for a much more trivial reason: if no such sequence $(\epsilon_N)$ exists, then every Cauchy sequence in $K$ is eventually constant.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me how to make a diagonal argument?  It is the only point that seems unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Are you familiar with the usual proof that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges (if $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences)?  I'm just referring to the method used in that proof.

Comment: I have learnt about it. But maybe it is a version differerent from what you are talking about. Could you please tell me by giving a link of sample proof and point out which part is called the diagnol argument?

Comment: See, for instance, Corollary 1.13 of http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.095/2015IAP/lecture1/padic.pdf.  The choice of $r_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ for each $n$ such that $|x_n-r_n|<1/n$ is what I meant by a "diagonal argument", though the exact setup there is slightly different from what I had in mind.  As I said in the answer, to generalize this with $\mathbb{Q}$ replaced by another ordered field you will need to replace $1/n$ by an appropriate $\epsilon_n$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!